Enmascarar o cambiar palabras de una URL con htaccess
la misión de hoy es pasar de dominio.es/root/views/dashboard/ a dominio.es/dashboard/ por medio de htaccess.
Les pondré mi htacces y luego explico
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 dominio.es/
ErrorDocument 301 dominio.es/

# Quitar extencion de las URL
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
# FIN quitar extencion de las URL

# Deshabilito las multi vistas y todas las peticiones que no existan las proceso en data.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ profesional.php [L]
</IfModule>

# TODO LO COMENTADO A PARTIR DE ACÁ, ES LO QUE HE INTENTADO PARA CAMBIAR LAS URL
#https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3wVVtSBxmNA
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^dashboard/$ /root/views/dashboard/
#RewriteRule ^(root|dashboard)$ /dashboard [NC]
#RewriteRule ^/root/views/dashboard/$ /dashboard/
#RewriteRule ^(/root/views/dashboard/).php /root/views/dashboard/ [QSA,L]
#RewriteRule ^/root/views/dashboard/?$ /dashboard
#RewriteRule ^dashboard/(.*)$ /root/views/dashboard/$1 [L,P]
#RewriteRule ^dashboard.php$ /root/views/dashboard.php


No importa si el ultimo bloque del htacces lo pongo al inicio o al final, el resultado es el mismo, NO HACE NADA!

Para ir al Dashboard, no mando ningún parámetro, es un link del index, ya en dash se evaluan las sesiones y otras cosas.

En la parte que comento # Deshabilito las multi vistas y todas las peticiones que no existan las proceso en data.php lo que hago es lo siguiente.



En mi sistema, muestro por cada perfil de usuario una url como esta dominio.es/userName




Es obvio que yo no tengo un archivo para cada usuario, lo que hago es que cuando alguien da clic en la url del perfil de un usuario, cojo la variable userName y por medio de htacces proceso TODO lo que no tenga un archivo propio, en un archivo que está en la raíz que se llama data.php




Este archivo data.php coge la variable userName y ya busca en la DB y se ve todo muy bien, esa parte funciona perfectamente.



El problema es que no quiero que las rutas del Dashboard, Perfil y otras, que estan en la misma carpeta de views se vean con esa estructura de url sino con la que pongo al inicio.
He visto muchos videos, he leído y seguido artículos, he leído el manual de htacces y la verdad es que (casi desde hace el inicio del proyecto) se me ha hecho imposible ocultar esa estructura de url.

Vean tanto este ejemplo como este otro ejemplo, en ambos capturan una palabra justamente después del dominio (la palabra dashboard en mi caso) y redirigen para que lo que realmente se muestre sea la ultima parte, osea la url real de donde está el recurso. Pero por alguna razón, aunque ponga esto al inicio, NO ME FUNCIONA!
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^dashboard$ /root/views/dashboard [NC]

Alguna idea??

Ya que no pude con esto, ayer decidí hacer un sistema de rutas para todo el proyecto, me quedó súper genial, pongo en cada ruta lo que quiero y funciona de maravilla  Dejaré esta pregunta abierta para ver porque es que a pesar de múltiples ejemplos, no pude pasar de una "url fea" a una "url bonita"

Haz hecho lo mejor del mundo, pero igual ahí respondí tu pregunta...

Prueba con
RewriteRule ^root/views/dashboard dashboard? [R=301,L]
Y te comento, he probado esto en https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/ y funciona correctamente.
Ingreso
http://dominio.es/root/views/dashboard
Y retorna
http://dominio.es/dashboard
Pueda que haya alguna otra regla que te de problemas.

puedes hacerlo asi:
RewriteEngine On

# Redirigir /root/views/dashboard/ a /dashboard/
RewriteRule ^root/views/dashboard/?$ /dashboard/ [R=301,L]

como funciona:
RewriteEngine On: Activa el módulo de reescritura.
RewriteRule ^root/views/dashboard/?$ /dashboard/ [R=301,L]: Esta línea hace la redirección:
^root/views/dashboard/?$: Este es un patrón de búsqueda que coincide con la URL que quieres redirigir. El ? después de dashboard/ permite que funcione tanto con como sin una barra inclinada al final.
/dashboard/: Es la nueva URL a la que quieres redirigir.
[R=301,L]: Especifica que es una redirección 301 (permanente), lo cual es bueno para SEO, y L indica que esta es la última regla que se debe aplicar si coincide.

No se si me expliqué mal al inicio, o sea, no quiero una redirección (Bryro esto me redirige a una ubicación que no existe). Lo que quiero es ENMASCARAR una url, es decir, quiero eliminar de la url del navegador la parte de "root/views/" para que en su lugar se vea "dominio.es/dashboard" o así dominio.es/admin/dashboard  (con otras palabras pues), pero esta última ubicación NO ES REAL, no existe, solo es una mascara, tal como lo pongo el el titulo. En los links que pongo en mi ultima edición lo hacen, cambian palabras y pasan de una "url fea" a una "url bonita"
